# Create System Preferences URL to Privacy Files and Folders in 10.15 Catalina

Tags: macos, preferences, privacy, url, catalina

In macOS you can create a link to the Automation section of the Privacy Pane in System Preferences by the following URL

```
x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Automation
```

Does anyone know the equivalent for the new Files and Folders section in Catalina, or a way to make macOS to print out all links?

I have tried running the apple script mentioned in a similar question about a link to Full Disk Access in Mojave, but this doesn't appear to return all sections (for example Input Monitoring and Files and Folders).

Answer (score 8):

List of URLs for reference (*updated for macOS Catalina & Mojave):

```
Accessibility Preference Pane
Main    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.universalaccess
Display x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.universalaccess?Seeing_Display
Zoom    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.universalaccess?Seeing_Zoom
VoiceOver   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.universalaccess?Seeing_VoiceOver
Descriptions    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.universalaccess?Media_Descriptions
Captions    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.universalaccess?Captioning
Audio   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.universalaccess?Hearing
Keyboard    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.universalaccess?Keyboard
Mouse & Trackpad    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.universalaccess?Mouse
Switch Control  x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.universalaccess?Switch
Dictation   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.universalaccess?SpeakableItems

Security & Privacy Preference Pane
Main    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security
General x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?General
FileVault   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?FDE
Firewall    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Firewall
Advanced    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Advanced
Privacy x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy
Privacy-Camera x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Camera
Privacy-Microphone  x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Microphone
Privacy-Automation  x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Automation
Privacy-AllFiles    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_AllFiles
Privacy-Accessibility   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Accessibility
Privacy-Assistive   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Assistive
Privacy-Location Services   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_LocationServices
Privacy-SystemServices  x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_SystemServices
Privacy-Advertising x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Advertising
Privacy-Contacts    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Contacts
Privacy-Diagnostics & Usage x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Diagnostics
Privacy-Calendars   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Calendars
Privacy-Reminders   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Reminders
Privacy-Facebook    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Facebook
Privacy-LinkedIn    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_LinkedIn
Privacy-Twitter x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Twitter
Privacy-Weibo   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Weibo
Privacy-Tencent Weibo   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_TencentWeibo

macOS Catalina 10.15:
Privacy-ScreenCapture   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_ScreenCapture
Privacy-DevTools    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_DevTools
Privacy-InputMonitoring x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_ListenEvent
Privacy-DesktopFolder   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_DesktopFolder
Privacy-DocumentsFolder x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_DocumentsFolder
Privacy-DownloadsFolder x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_DownloadsFolder
Privacy-NetworkVolume   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_NetworkVolume
Privacy-RemovableVolume x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_RemovableVolume
Privacy-SpeechRecognition   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_SpeechRecognition

Dictation & Speech Preference Pane
Dictation   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.speech?Dictation
Text to Speech  x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.speech?TTS
Sharing Preference Pane
Main    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preferences.sharing
Screen Sharing  x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preferences.sharing?Services_ScreenSharing
File Sharing    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preferences.sharing?Services_PersonalFileSharing
Printer Sharing x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preferences.sharing?Services_PrinterSharing
Remote Login    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preferences.sharing?Services_RemoteLogin
Remote Management   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preferences.sharing?Services_ARDService
Remote Apple Events x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preferences.sharing?Services_RemoteAppleEvent
Internet Sharing    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preferences.sharing?Internet
Bluetooth Sharing   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preferences.sharing?Services_BluetoothSharing

Software update x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preferences.softwareupdate?client=softwareupdateapp
```

Ref : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652598/cocoa-button-opens-a-system-preference-page/48139877#48139877